# método - función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Crea un método que reciba dos valores y devuelva la suma de estos después de imprimirlos en pantalla solo si el resultado de la suma de ambos es mayor que 100.

```
function suma (numero1, numero2){
  var numero1 = numero1
   var numero2 = numero2
    return numero1 + numero2
}
document.write(suma(10,13));
```

De momento solo tengo esto

Elemento de lista

Comment: `if((numero1+numero2) > 100)` por otra parte no tienes que volver a declarar las variable ya que se reciben por parámetros.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, ten en cuenta que `document.write()` es una **mala práctica**.

Ahora bien, como te lo dijo @Christian en los comentarios, no necesitas volver a definir los números, pues se reciben en los parámetros, podrías usar un [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Por no usar `document.write()`, podrías poner más contenido al  documento alterando la propiedad [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) de [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/body)

```js
function suma(n1, n2) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<p>${n1 + n2}</p>`;
  if ((n1 + n2) > 100) return n1 + n2;
}

console.log(suma(25, 34)) // undefined
console.log(suma(85, 15)) // undefined
console.log(suma(15, 213)) // 228
```

Comment: También podrías usar los backticks

Comment: @Christian Gracias por ese aporte, no los usaba porque en general no los uso en strings muy largos. Saludos.

Comment: saludos rodrigo, me ha servido para hacerme una idea, muchas gracias